# Delete from gridview through mySql source

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I populate from a mysql database. I have my surrogate key column (`id`) in the gridview, and a delete option for every row.

Problem is that I don't know how I can specify what `id` I want to delete in my database delete command.

I got the following so far:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int row = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("id").ToString()); // THIS IS WRONG! 

    String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySql"].ToString(); //Conn string

    MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString); //Objekt
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(); //cmd objekt

    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM `PostDb` WHERE `id` = " + row;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection;

    mySqlConnection.Open();
    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    mySqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Something is wrong with my`row`. I have no idea if the rest I'm doing is correct though.

I get a null reference

Comment: Still looking for an answer ?

Comment: i got it working. will post an answer when i can :-)

Comment: Great. I was about to answer that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the STAR (*) from your QUERY like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM `PostDb` WHERE `id` = " + row;
```

Comment: i tried that. But im getting the following from my row variable
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: is PostDB a Tablename or a Database Name If Database you must specify the table like **DELETE FROM PostDB.your_table_name WHERE id = ...**

Comment: The query is correct, but the null reference is coming from "row", which means that it for some reason cant find id?